# why i have the error "No instance for (Ord Documento) arising from a use of ‘insert" wit haskell

Tags: eclipse, haskell

Im beginner with haskell and im trying to execute my method mostrarDocumento, setting Documentos and String(year), and the method should return all documents that have the same year , but i having the error :

```
    No instance for (Ord Documento) arising from a use of ‘insert’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      insert docu (mostrarDocumento' documentos anno)
    In the expression:
      do { insert docu (mostrarDocumento' documentos anno) }
    In the expression:
      if esAnnoIgual docu anno then
          do { insert docu (mostrarDocumento' documentos anno) }
      else
          mostrarDocumento' documentos anno
```

Someone can help me with my code?

```
module Documento where
import Data.List
import Data.Function (on)
import System.IO()

type Revista = String
type IdD = String
type Anno = String
type Titulo = String
type Resumen = String
type Secciones = [String]

data Documento = D (Revista, IdD, Anno, Titulo, Resumen, Secciones)deriving Show
type Documentos = [Documento]

anio :: Documento -> Anno
anio (D (_,_,anio,_,_,_)) = anio


pintarDocOrd :: Documentos -> IO()
pintarDocOrd [] = return ()
pintarDocOrd (dc:dcs) = do
        print dc
        pintarDocOrd dcs

mostrarDocumeto :: Documentos -> String-> IO()
mostrarDocumeto [] _ =  return ()
mostrarDocumeto documentos anno = do
      let documento = mostrarDocumento' documentos anno
      pintarDocOrd documento

mostrarDocumento' :: Documentos -> String -> Documentos
mostrarDocumento' [] _ = []
mostrarDocumento' (docu:documentos) anno =
                                        if esAnnoIgual docu anno then do
                                          insert docu (mostrarDocumento' documentos anno)
                                         else
                                           mostrarDocumento' documentos anno

esAnnoIgual :: Documento -> String -> Bool
esAnnoIgual documento anno
          | anio documento == anno = True
          | otherwise = False
```

Comment: First of all, I recommend reading the documentation for `insert` to see if it's doing what you want. I don't know whatever language your code is in, so it's a little difficult for me to be sure.  But to fix your problem, you need to make `Documento` an instance of `Ord`. Fortunately, GHC will do that for you if you add `Ord` to the deriving clause of the type. That is, change `deriving Show` to `deriving (Show, Ord)` at the end of the `data Documento = ...` declaration.

Comment: You should explain - in English - what you want `mostrarDocumento'` to do.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:insert):

```
insert :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So `insert` works on a list of `a`s, but only if that `a` is of typeclass `Ord`, i.e. that have an order defined on them. So try:

```
data Documento = ... deriving (Show, Ord)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is what you are trying to do:

```
mostrarDocumento' :: Documentos -> String -> Documentos
mostrarDocumento' [] _ = []
mostrarDocumento' (docu:documentos) anno =
    if esAnnoIgual docu anno
      then docu : (mostrarDocumento' documentos anno)
      else mostrarDocumento' documentos anno
```

which is the same as:

```
mostrarDocumento' docs = filter (\d -> esAnnoIgual d anno) docs
```